# Substitution of different occurrences of a string with changing patterns

Tags: python, parsing, strings, json

I need to parse an invalid JSON string in which I find many repetitions of the same key, like the following snippet:

```
[...]
"term" : {"Entry" : "value1", [.. other data ..]},
"term" : {"Entry" : "value2", [.. other data ..]},
[...]
```

I thought of appending a suffix to each key, and I do it using the following code:

```
word = "term"
offending_string = '"term" : {"Entry"'
replacing_string_template = '"%s_d" : {"Entry"'

counter = 0
index = 0
while index != -1:
    # result is the string containing the JSON data
    index = result.find(offending_string, index)
    result = result.replace(offending_string,
                replacing_string_template % (word, counter), 1)
    counter += 1
```

It works, but I'd like to know if it is a good approach and if you would do this in a different way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import json

def fixup(pairs):
   return pairs

decoded = json.loads(bad_json, object_pairs_hook = fixup)
```

object_pairs_hook is a more recent addition. If you have an older version of python you may not have it. The resulting python object will contain lists of pairs (including duplicates) rather then dictionaries.

Comment: +1 great! But I doubt it will work, because this code is deployed under Google App Engine, that uses an old version of python that doesn't even contain the json module. I have to `import simplejson as json` from django.

Comment: @Andrea, the current version of simplejson does support the object_pairs_hook. Even if Google App Engine doesn't have the latest version, you can probably download and install your own copy of simplejson for your project.